# CoreData Relationships, Delete Rules and Referential Integrity

Tags: core-data, cascading-deletes, referential-integrity

Two entities (Archive & Item) each reference a third entity (Photo). The preferred behavior is that Photo row B is only deleted when there are no longer any reference to it from any other entity instance. The observed behavior is that when Photo B row is associated to an entity such as Archive, Archive appears to take ownership of Photo B. If I delete Item, Photo B is not deleted. However, if I delete Archive Photo B is deleted even though Item references it.

Is there a way to configure this such that the only time Photo B row is delete is when there are no other entities referencing it?

[image: ERD]

Comment: What delete rules are you using on the relationships between `Archive`, `Item`, and `Photo`?

Comment: See the diagram... cascade from Archive & Item. Nullify from Photo